# Is there a python function to override variables instead of completely rewriting them?

Tags: python, json

Im trying to basically use JSON as a db for my python discord bot, and I have noticed, that when I save my new changes to the database, each other property of the database is wiped (corresponding to the specific server im changing info of) except the one im changing, im sure its something that has to do with how im saving a None variable, "", but anyway, this is my code:

```py
role_nation = ""
role_mayor = ""
role_allied = ""
role_enemy = ""
role_foreigner = ""
nation_name = ""
servers = {}
@client.command()
async def setup(ctx, arg, role):
    global role_nation
    global role_mayor
    global role_allied
    global role_enemy
    global role_foreigner
    global nation_name
    if arg == "nation":
        role_nation = role
    if arg == "allied":
        role_allied = role
    if arg == "mayor":
        role_mayor = role
    if arg == "enemy":
        role_enemy = role
    if arg == "foreigner":
        role_foreigner = role
    if arg == "set_nation":
        nation_name = role
    roles = {"nation_name": nation_name,
            "nation": role_nation,
            "allied": role_allied,
            "mayor": role_mayor,
            "enemy": role_enemy,
            "foreigner": role_foreigner}
    servers[ctx.guild.id]= roles
    await ctx.send("Successfully saved your preferences.")
    await ctx.send(str(servers))
    with open('servers.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(servers, fp)
    fp.close()
    role_nation = ""
    role_mayor = ""
    role_allied = ""
    role_enemy = ""
    role_foreigner = ""
    nation_name = ""
```

Comment: Why are you explicitly setting each value to `""` at the end of the function?

Comment: @chepner Completely forgot, was part of some debug stuff. +1

Answer (score 3):

When you dump an object into a json file then it will overwrite the whole file with what was dumped. This is expected behavior. What you need to do is when the server first starts up you need to load the previous json file that you have into memory and overwrite your `servers` variable. After that the data is in memory so you can add, remove or update it and then when you need to save it to the file again then dump.

json has no builtin database features like indexing, transactions or updating single objects. It simply converts an object into a string so that you can dump that string into a file and overwrite that file.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot that I had each variable reset at the end of the function, thanks @chepner